# Detecting Pinch gesture beginning on iPhone MapView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

We are developing a map based application for iPhone. We need to detect beginning of drag and pinch gestures on MapView.

We are able to detect beginning of dragging using regionWillChange delegate method. We are unable to detect beginning of pinch gesture.

We are looking for a method for detecting beginning of pinching gesture. Is it possible on MapView?

Thanks in Advance.

Edit: 
We have tried with following code but it didn't work.

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(checkpinch)]; 
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:pinch]; 
[pinch release];
```

The double tap gesture recognizer is working on the MapView using similar code.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *Tap= [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(checktap)]; 
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:Tap]; 
[Tap release];
```

Answer (score 4):

Perfect and easy solution.

first add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in you .h file
than add following two methods in you .m file

```
    -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer

{
    return  YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer

{
    return  YES;
}
```

make following change in viewdidload

```
[self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourmethod)];
[pinch setDelegate:self];
[pinch setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
[pinch release];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(youemethod)];
[tap setDelegate:self];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer apple sample code:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WorldCities/Introduction/Intro.html

The code illustrates both drag and zoom actions on MKMapView

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We referred to the example code but cannot find how to handle pinch and double tap gesture detection.

Comment: To enable pinch gesture detection, make sure that zoomEnabled property is set to YES. You can then change the zoom level by calling setRegion:animated: method.

Comment: we have checked with zoomEnabled property set. It is still not detecting beginning of pinch gesture.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Gesture Recognizer to your MapView and wire up to IBAction to handle the particular guesture .. 
and in the IBAction you can detect the beginning / end of the particular guesture..

Example :

```
- (IBAction)handlePanGuesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recogonizer {
    if (recogonizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // do stuff
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. We tried using provided delegate method. We can detect tap gesture but cannot detect pinch gesture using it. We tried using UITapRecognizer and UIPinchRecognizer

Comment: you may want to post the code for us to take a look, as per documentation the state will get the gesture action method called with the stateBegan.